# How to set/check msb on a generalized inttype?

Tags: c++, templates, bit-manipulation

I have the following snippets somewhere in my current code base:

```
// uint32_t id; defined somewhere
bool msb_set = id & 0x80000000
```

And would like to change this to something more flexible:

```
using id_t = uint64_t;
id_t id;
bool msb_set = id & 0x80000000  // uh-oh, semantic change for any other differently sized inttype
```

How can I most easily generate the appropriate literal depending on the concrete inttype I'm using? I'm looking for sth along the lines of

```
numeric_constants<id_t>::int_with_msb_set();
```

Comment: Does this have to work for signed integers? If so, are we allowed to assume two's complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that returns the masks you want:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T getMsbMask()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T>)
        return T(-1) - T(-1) / 2;
    else
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    // Unsigned branch computes 0b11111... - 0b01111...
    // Signed branch assumes two's complement, which will soon be the standard:
    // http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html
}
```

[Demo and tests on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/DCrEIu).

The compiler can evidently figure out these constant values at compile-time, so there is no speed penalty whatsoever.

The other obvious solution would just be a struct with specializations for each type (akin to `std::numeric_limits`).

Comment: I suspect your use of  min() also presumes that signed is implemented using 2's complement. I think any solution will have to make some technical assumption about what a "top bit" is.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, it states that assumption (and why it is justified) in the comment below it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the unsigned version basically makes the same assumption in it's belief of how -1 is represented.

Comment: @GemTaylor Not really. The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2) specifies that for unsigned integers, all values are to be considered modulo `2^N` where `N` is the number of bits in the representation. Thus, `-1` is guaranteed to be equivalent to `(2^N) - 1`, the maximum representable value (which _is_ guaranteed to have all bits set).

Comment: @GemTaylor And [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.fundamental#4) is the standard for C++ 14. Also mind the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a `std::bitset` to check if the most significant bit is set.  You can convert the number to a `std::bitset` and then return the most significant bit like

```
template<typename T> 
constexpr bool mb_set(T value)
{
    constexpr auto size = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;
    return std::bitset<size>(value)[size - 1];
}
```

testing this on clang with `-O2` or `-O3` optimizes the function away to a `shr` instruction.

Comment: This only partially answers the question, as it only checks whether the msb is set. It does not give the mask nor does it provide a way to modify the msb.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ah, blast, I missed the set and just saw check.  I'll leave this as a way to just check the msb.